# How to use the GAM tool to print out title and department information for G Suite users

Tags: google-workspace

I have tried the command "gam print organizations.0.title users >test.csv" to print out user info that includes title and department information to a csv file. However, it said "organizations.0.title is not a valid argument for gam print".

[image]

I couldn't find the right format to call titles and departments from the the official wiki(https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/GAM3CSVListings).

Please help if anyone knows about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer too...bashed against the keyboard for a while and found you can:

```
    gam print users organizations
```

That'll print primaryEmail, organizations, organizations.0.title, organizations.0.primary, organizations.0.customType, organizations.0.department, organizations.0.description, organizations.0.costCenter